# Wordpress - Can't open anchor in IE and Safari but works fine in Chrome

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
   <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){


            $desc = $recent["post_content"];
            $dessWithoutImg = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $desc);
            $withoutLinks = preg_replace('/<\/?a[^>]*>/','', $dessWithoutImg);
            $desc = mb_strimwidth($withoutLinks, 0, 200, '...');

            echo $recent["ID"];

            echo '
            <div class="column small-12 medium-6 margin-bottom-xsmall post-panel">
                <div class="panel-tan">
                    <a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">
                        <h5>' . $recent["post_title"] . '</h5>
                    </a>'
                    . $desc .
                '</div>
            </div>';
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Link
http://b20.2c7.mwp.accessdomain.com

The above link there is some recent posts at the bottom of the page if you click these pages in Chrome then it takes you to the page however if you click on one of these posts in Safari or IE Yet to check FF. It opens to a file not found.

I thought that the point of Get-permalink was to return what permalink is being used and in this instance it is returning the ID. Is there a way to modify my code so it outputs the post name.

**More information**
My Permalink settings are set to post name.

Has anyone come across this oddity before?

Comment: you means latest news?

Comment: If you mean the latest news, it works on IE11

Comment: Yeah thanks guys I just re-wrote it in a different way not using the recent_posts query